# Function.prototype.call does not invoke method with provided context

Tags: javascript, function.prototype

```
var userData = {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Tim'
}

function Userdata( id, name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.getData = () => { 
        console.log('Name: ' + this.name + ' and Id ' + this.id ) 
      }
}

var ud = new Userdata(1, 'Tom');
ud.getData.call(userData);
```

Output: Name: Tom and Id 1 (why)

I though that ud.getData.**call**(userData) will set the this to userData when calling function, which is not happening.

[repl here](https://repl.it/repls/WelcomeLinenPorcupine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrow functions don't have their own `this`, they **always** close over the `this` where they're defined, and so they'll ignore any `this` specified by how they're called (whether via `call` or `apply` or not).

Comment: So this is kind of a bug fix (on context binding) with es6 new syntax? or other particular reason for it?

Comment: @ManasviSareen: It's the purpose of arrow functions, to make it easy to create a function that closes over `this` (and `arguments` and `super`) rather than having its own bindings for them. If you don't want that feature, use `function` or method syntax instead. (Method syntax wouldn't apply to your code snippet.)

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular function:

```js
var userData = {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Tim'
}

function Userdata(id, name) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.getData = function() {
    console.log('Name: ' + this.name + ' and Id ' + this.id)
  };
}

var ud = new Userdata(1, 'Tom');
ud.getData.call(userData);
```